# Redis - SQL server and vise versa

Tags: sql, redis

I want to know is it possible to get data from sql server to redis server directly?
Can we create direct communication from redis to sql or vise versa?
so through SQL server i can fetch the redis data

Comment: AFAIK no - you'll have to do that with coding.

Comment: If you want to save data from Redis to SQL Server, you can start with [redis rdb tools](https://github.com/sripathikrishnan/redis-rdb-tools), which includes a good parser. [pyodbc](https://code.google.com/p/pyodbc/) can then be used to save the parsed data to SQL Server.

Comment: ok i got some work around for this http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/19954/Execute-NET-Code-under-SQL-Server just posting this so it may help for some one

Comment: @Abhiram if you feel that your comment answers your question, go ahead and post it as answer, and mark it as the answer to your question.